# FactoMineR/factoextra visualize all the clusters in the dendrogram

Tags: r, plot, dendrogram, dendextend, factoextra

I performed a hierarchical clustering on a dataframe using the HCPC function of the package FactoMineR. Problem is, I cannot visualize the number of clusters I asked when I draw the dendrogram using factoextra.
Here is below a reproducible example of my problem

```
model <- HCPC(iris[,1:4], nb.clust = 5)
```

[image: Factor Map]there are indeed 5 clusters above

```
fviz_dend(model, k = 5,
          cex = 0.7,                     
          palette = "default",              
          rect = TRUE, rect_fill = TRUE, 
)
```

[image]
But just 3 mapped within the dendrogram

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I bumped into the same problem: the `fviz_dend` function would always return what it considers to be the optimal amount of clusters, even when I tried to override this – either in the `HCPC` or in the `fviz_dend` functions.

One way to fix this while sticking to FactoMineR and factoextra would be to change the default amount of clusters calculated by the HCPC function:

```
model$call$t$nb.clust = 5
```

And then run the `fviz_dend` function.

This should return [the result that you were expecting](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YVSZ1.png).

Answer (score 2):

You can just use the dendextend R package with the `color_branches` function:

```
library(dendextend)
dend <- USArrests %>% dist %>% hclust(method = "ave") %>% as.dendrogram
dd <- color_branches(dend,5)
plot(dd)
```

[image]